# Creating Automatic Skype Listener

Tags: .net, skype, skype4com

I need to build up a Skype Listener server for one of my project. It will:
1. Host 8 different dummy Skype accounts.
2. All accounts will already have associated:
  (a) Already Recorded audio files
  (b) pre-recorded video files
3. A Skype call to any of these Skype accounts will automatically initiate the pre-recorded audio or the video depending upon the call type.

Problem:
 1. I am unable to install more than one Skype client on one machine. This is required if I install virtual webcam and need to change the video source to virtual web cam and play pre-recorded video. If i don't install more than one client, it is always playing the same video for calls to any contact
2.How to automate the call recieving on Skype. There are URI for initiating the call but none for receiving the call.
3. **A wish** : Can we integrate receiving call event of Skype to kick our .NET code?

Any immediate help will be highly appreciated

Regards
Raj

Answer (score 0):

In Skype for Desktop (Windows) you can setup automatic answering of incoming calls in the call settings (advanced).

And to start multiple instances, use `Skype.exe /secondary`, it'll allow you as many instances as you want.

You cannot integrate this with .NET, or any other 3rd party application, without using [SkypeKit](https://dev.skype.com/skypekit)

[image: Skype Call Settings]

Comment: Hi Claus  Thanks for the reply. However I am aware of this method. What i actually want is the way to do it with SkypeKit.  Any help in that area?